Checkbox - align center
On Yes/No Checkbox - JSON sample, there is a code allowing you to show checkbox (square) for a YES/NO column regardless of the current value of the field (by default checkbox only shows if YES is selected).
The JSON code works absolutely fine, however I'd like to have the checkbox horizontally aligned to the center of the field. At present, the checkbox is horizontally align to the left.

Can you add any screenshot how it is looking currently and how you want to show it exactly?

If you want to align the checkbox horizontally, you can add padding-left style for outermost div element as per your requirements.
Example:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "padding-left": "15px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField,'CheckboxComposite','Checkbox')",
        "class": "=if(@currentField,'ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary','ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary')+' ms-fontSize-l'"
      },
      "style": {
        "cursor": "pointer"
      },
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "setValue",
        "actionInput": {
          "YesNoColumnInternalName": "=if(@currentField , '0' , '1' )"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

You can adjust the padding value as per your column width in place of 15px in JSON.
Where YesNoColumnInternalName is an internal name of your Yes/No column in SharePoint list. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?
Output:


Thank you @ganesh-sanap-mvp
